# I need to flatten this XML data, so i can import it to Excel

Tags: c#, xml, excel, ms-access

I've been trying for days to get this data into Excel or Access, but i have little experience with XML / XSD. I dont know what is the best approach when it comes to importing data into Excel/Access. Excel doesn't support nested elements afaik. Access dont seem to bother with the linking of nested data. Sooo i might end up flattening the structure my self for Excel, which in either case would be the program i need for final analysis.

I would like it flat or even csv format, but my concern is the size of the file. I have a subset of the data now an this xml file is already 11Meg and its a few precent of the total data.

This is my XML file, a subset.

```
    <Root>
    <Delivery>
    <Database>xxxxxxx</Database>
    <Path>SomeUNCPath</Path>
<Vessel>
<SysFolder>internalfolder</Sysfolder>
<MoreData>1</MoreData>
<EvenMoreData>2</EvenMoreData>
<Depths>
<NumberOfItems>2</NumberOfItems>
<Depth> 
<MoreData>1</MoreData>
<EvenMoreData>2</EvenMoreData>
</Depth>
<Depth>
...
</Depth>
<Vessel>
<SysFolder>Anotherinternalfolder</Sysfolder>
<MoreData>1</MoreData>
<EvenMoreData>2</EvenMoreData>
<Depths>
<NumberOfItems>2</NumberOfItems>
<Depth> 
<MoreData>1</MoreData>
<EvenMoreData>2</EvenMoreData>
</Depth>
<Depth>
...
</Depth>
<EngineRoot>
<SysFolder>internalfolder</Sysfolder>
<NumberOfEngines>5</NumberOfEngines>
<Engine>5 Elements of this with data</Engine>
</EngineRoot>
<EngineRoot>
<SysFolder>Anotherinternalfolder</Sysfolder>
<NumberOfEngines>5</NumberOfEngines>
<Engine>5 Elements of this with data</Engine>
</EngineRoot>
```

Comment: You could try the [Xml To Csv Conversion Tool](http://xmltocsv.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you. That tool will do the job i guess. Have to test it.